# jQuery UI Modal Dialog Closes Immediately on JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui

We are opening a simple jQuery UI dialog from a JSP.

We see it for a split second, and it closes immediately. The dialog needs to stay open.

JSP code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function openPopUp() {
        alert('OpenPopUp() called');
          $("#dialog-1").dialog(
                    {
                        width: 600,
                        height: 400,
                        open: function(event, ui)
                        {
                            var textarea = $('<textarea style="height: 276px;">');
                            $(textarea).redactor({
                                focus: true,
                                maxHeight: 300,
                            });
                        }
                     });
    }

</script>
```

Down below in the JSP, the Div and then the button that opens the popup:

```
<html:html>

    <div id="dialog-1" title="Dialog Title goes here..." style="display: none;">This my first jQuery UI Dialog!</div>

    ...

    <button id="disregard_1" onclick="openPopUp();">Open Dialog</button>

</html:html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your initialization should be separate imo.
Check the API/[examples](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) on jQuery UI and more in detail the modal form.

```
// init
var dialog = $('#selector').dialog({/*your options*/});

// bind event
$('#event-trigger').click(function(){
    dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

To wrap this up in your situation:

```
// dom ready
$(function(){
    var myPopup = $('#dialog-1');

    // custom function
    function openPopUp() {
        alert('OpenPopUp() called');
        myPopup.dialog('open'); 
    }

    // init
    myPopup.dialog({
        autoOpen: false, // prevent it from opening by default
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        open: function(event, ui){
            var textarea = $('<textarea style="height: 276px;">');

            $(textarea).redactor({
                focus: true,
                maxHeight: 300,
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I hope you see the difference between initializing onClick and calling something that has been initialized already.